# Ruby hashes of status counts

Tags: ruby, hash-map

I have a method that takes a model object, reads through its children and returns a hash of status counts. It should only return a count on a status if one exists.

This method works, but I was wondering if there are a cleaner, more Rubyish way to write it.

The `batch_details` table is getting very large, so if possible I'd like not to access it twice.

```
def batch_status
   batch_status = {
      'ready' => 0,
      'processing' => 0,
      'error' =>  0,
      'purchase' => 0,
      'completed' => 0
   }

   self.batch_details.each do |bd|
      batch_status[bd.status] = batch_status[bd.status] + 1
   end   
   batch_status['count'] = self.batch_details.count
   batch_status.delete_if {|k, v| v == 0 }
   return batch_status
end

2.1.2 :002 > b.batch_status
 => {"completed"=>4, "count"=>4}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array#group_by` to produce a hash keyed by status. Then follow that by a `map` to collect the counts. You'll get an array of key/value pairs, so use `Hash[]` to make that into a proper hash:

```
def batch_status
  counts = self.batch_details.group_by(&:status).map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }
  Hash[counts]
end
```

Alternatively, you can use use your current approach, just shortened a bit

```
def batch_status
  self.batch_details.reduce({}) do |counts, details|
    counts[details.status] = (counts[details.status] || 0) + 1
  end
end
```

---

Edit: Completely overlooked the `"count"` key. I muddies the picture a little, but you could do something like this for code blocks 1 and 2 above

```
def batch_status
  counts = self.batch_details.group_by(&:status).map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }
  counts << ["count", self.batch_details.count]
  Hash[counts]
end
```

and

```
def batch_status
  counts = { "count" => self.self.batch_details.count }
  self.batch_details.reduce(counts) do |counts, details|
    counts[details.status] = (counts[details.status] || 0) + 1
    counts
  end
end
```

Or, as Cary Swoveland suggests:

```
def batch_status
  counts = { "count" => self.self.batch_details.count }
  counts.default = 0
  self.batch_details.reduce(counts) do |counts, details|
    counts[details.status] += 1
    counts
  end
end
```

Which cleans it up nicely. Further cleanup could be done by using `each_with_object` in place of `reduce`:

```
def batch_status
  counts = { "count" => self.self.batch_details.count }
  counts.default = 0
  self.batch_details.each_with_object(counts) do |counts, details|
    counts[details.status] += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: One possible change to your last `batch_status`--which I think reads quite well--is to add `counts.default = 0` after the first line and then use `+= 1` in the block.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good idea - I'll add that

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of @Flambino's second suggestion, which starts with an empty hash, to avoid the step of deleting keys whose values are zero.

```
def batch_status
  self.batch_details.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|bd,h| batch_status[bd.status] += 1}
                    .merge({"count"=>self.batch_details.count})
end
```

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis after Hash.new(0). Cannot edit...

Comment: Thanks, TNT. I thought I had fixed that, but it's fixed now.